# Log in to windows by .bat file

Tags: batch-file

Here's the situation: I've got .bat file that is being started by windows scheduler every 15 min. However, when system  logs off user - actions are not being performed. I'd like to know, if it is possible to add some code to .bat file to make it log in to system again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user logs out, if the screen goes to a CTRL+ALT+DEL login screen, good-luck-chuck. No one has found a way to force windows to recognize CTRL+ALT+DEL from any programming language. Not even VBScript SENDKEYS will do it. However, if it goes directly to the user login to enter the name and password you can create a small .vbs sendkeys script to auto-login the user prior to running your .bat:

```
login.vbs

set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WSCript.shell")

wshShell.sendkeys "Username"
wscript.sleep 1000
wshShell.sendkeys "{Tab}"
wscript.sleep 1000
wshShell.sendkeys "Password"
wscript.sleep 1000
wshShell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Quit
```

Throw it into windows scheduler to run even if user is logged off. Or better yet, if you want to have it auto-login the user say 15 minutes after they log out, you can add it to the local Group Policy for that machine:

> In RUN type gpedit.msc navigate to Local Computer Policy -> User
>   Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Scripts (Logon/Logoff) Double
>   click on Logoff and hit Add... In script name, enter the path of your
>   .vbs and hit ok. At the beginning of the .vbs file, add

```
wscript.sleep 900000
```

That will force it to wait 15 minutes before running the rest of the script automatically when a user logs off.

Comment: Thanks, now it looks clear - at least I know that it is almost impossible . But script didn't work :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in the Tasksheduler wheter to run the task too if the user is logged off. Activate that and it should work fine.

Comment: I admit, its not a answer to your question, but a solution for your problem :)

Comment: Yes, I know that :) But the point is that my .bat launches SAP Logon application, so if user is logged off this action cannot be performed. Is there any way to make automatic login into system when scheduler starts task ?

Comment: ah: this makes sense now. you could try to execute the commands with the runas parameter? (http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: Won't help. As I see after logging in system - SAP Logon windows is absent,but process(saplogon.exe) is running .

Comment: SAP's single sign-on mechanism is really odd and non-standard.  You may need to concentrate specifically on that and ask in an SAP forum.  If it helps, you will probably run into the same problems if you try to run the script via a remote session (psexec), so that may be easier for debugging that logging off and waiting.